# Why do I get new values for defined variables?

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to calculate a shift with a curve fit. I define my known variables and have one unknown variable. When I use the logifunc the variables in my p0 aren't the define known values. Instead I get for every variable a new value.

```
Vergleich2['Wind']=Vergleich2.index

x2=Vergleich2.T.iloc[7]
y2=Vergleich2.T.iloc[6]
A2=popt[0]
b2=popt[1]
k2=popt[2]
off2=popt[3]

def logifunc(x2,A2,b2,k2,x0,off2):
    return A2 / (1 + b2 * np.exp(k2 * (x2+x0)))+off2

x_data2 = Vergleich2['Wind']
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(logifunc, x2,y2,p0 = [A2,b2,k2,2,off2])

my popt is: 
100.589
449.427
-0.695534
0.0554911

the popt2 output is:
100.204
846.734
-0.767603
0.517314
0.393996
```

Why does every value of the variables change?

Comment: Well, isn't that what `curve_fit` is meant to do: change all the parameters to better fit the input data. If it wouldn't change the parameters, what else can it do? Note that `curve_fit` allows putting bounds on the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want a formula with fixed values ​​and only one x0 that you can change to move the curve on the x-axis. The x0 should be the best shift value so that as many points as possible are close to the new curve. Do you have a suggestion on how I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a second function that fixes all parameters except `x0`:

```
def logifunc(x2,A2,b2,k2,x0,off2):
    return A2 / (1 + b2 * np.exp(k2 * (x2+x0)))+off2

def logifunc_x0(x2,x0):
    return A2 / (1 + b2 * np.exp(k2 * (x2+x0)))+off2

popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(logifunc_x0, x2, y2, p0=[2])
```